# Conditional template rendering with props in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I'm trying to make a toggle button so that a hamburger menu opens when clicked.

I made the boolean "clicked" property in "App.vue", passed it down to "Navbar.vue", and now I want to be able to click in the navbar to toggle the "clicked" property to "true" or "false" to make the backdrop and drawer show or not show.

I tried to use an "emit", and it seems to work, but the template isn't responding to the "clicked" variable and is showing even though it's false.

In the code below, what part did I get wrong? How do you implement conditional rendering with props? Can someone help?

---

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <NavBar :clicked="clicked" @toggleDrawer="toggleMenu()" />
  <BackDrop :clicked="clicked" />
  <SideDrawer :clicked="clicked" />
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { NavBar, BackDrop, SideDrawer },

  setup() {
    const clicked = ref(false);

    const toggleMenu = () => {
      clicked.value = !clicked.value;
    };
    return { clicked, toggleMenu };
  },
};
</script>
```

---

**NavBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar">
  /* MORE CODE */
    <div class="hamburger_menu" @click="toggleEvent">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineEmits, defineProps } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  clicked: Boolean,
});

const emit = defineEmits(["toggleDrawer"]);

const toggleEvent = () => {
  console.log("toggleEvent running");
  emit("toggleDrawer", !props.clicked);
};
</script>
```

**Backdrop.vue**

```
<template v-if="props.clicked">
  <div class="backdrop"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps } from "vue";
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const props = defineProps({
  clicked: Boolean,
});
</script>
```

**SideDrawer.vue**

```
<template v-if="props.clicked">
  <div class="sidedrawer"></div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from "vue";
const props = defineProps({
  clicked: Boolean,
});
</script>
```

---

Am I passing in the prop wrong? Does "props.clicked" not work in "v-if"'s or templates? How should I implement the "v-if" with the "clicked" property I have?

Answer (score 2):

As @neha-soni said,

> **After running the code, it is working fine**

Vue recommends to use kebab-cased event listeners in templates. Your `toggleDrawer` will auto-converted into kebab case when you use it in the parent component. So In app.vue you can  use it like `@toggle-drawer`,

```
 <NavBar :clicked="clicked" @toggle-drawer="toggleMenu()" />
```

From vue doc [link](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events)

> event names provide an automatic case transformation. Notice we emitted a camelCase event, but can listen for it using a kebab-cased listener in the parent. As with props casing, we recommend using kebab-cased event listeners in templates.

Comment: I think it is written as `can listen` which means we can listen as kebab-cased syntax but listening with their original casing also works. Can you explain it please?

Answer (score 1):

After running the code, it is working fine. I have a few feedbacks to remove unnecessary code which is creating confusion and then you can see its working.

1. Because props are immutable (read-only) in the child component that means their value will not be changed so there is no point to pass props value back (by doing `emit("toggleDrawer", !props.clicked)`) to the parent because the parent already has their original status.
2. Another point is, you are passing the data (props data) from the event by doing `emit("toggleDrawer", !props.clicked)` but not using it when calling the function `@toggleDrawer="toggleMenu()"` in `App.vue`, so better to remove this data passing code.
3. The `clicked` property is updating in the parent (`App.vue`) as well as inside the child components. Just console and print the `clicked` property in the child and parent template like `{{ clicked }}` at the top and you can see the updated status-

```
const toggleMenu = () => {
  console.log('Before______', clicked.value)
  clicked.value = !clicked.value;
  console.log('After______', clicked.value)
};
```